# Why does Windows store not start after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8 Professional

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-store, windows-store-app

Many people who have taken the $39 offer to upgrade to Windows 8 Professional are having this problem. Most of the apps on the Start screen don't work. This is only occurring with customers that have upgraded from Windows 7 or Windows XP to Windows 8 Professional.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the default Administrator account. The documentation on this account clearly explains this account cannot be connected to a Microsoft Account and its access to the Windows Store thus will be limited. In my testing not a single application from the store will actually work, even though I was able to install the application, and no problems were reported. The application in question simply refuses to run. I can promise you this problem is NOT just happening to customers who upgrade form Windows XP.

Comment: I think Ramhound should submit his comment as the definitive answer.  I installed Windows 8 from scratch (NO upgrade), I have an ordinary user, when I try to install an app from the Store I get a message 'Add your Microsoft account'.  Do you get that too Dave Posh?

Comment: @GuyThomas - If I post an answer it will just be given downvotes.